# Confused about memory usage

Tags: memory, ram

I'm working with a small Pololu 3pi robot. It has 32KB of flash, **2KB of SRAM** and 1KB of EEPROM. I ran the following code on the robot:

```
#include <pololu/3pi.h>

int main(){
    int nums[1000];

    nums[0] = 50;
    nums[999] = 100;

    clear();
    print_long(nums[0]); // prints 50
    lcd_goto_xy(0, 1);
    print_long(nums[999]); // prints 100

    while(1);
}
```

My expectation was that it would crash because it's run out of RAM 
to store the entire `nums` array. But not only did it not crash, it also printed the numbers correctly as they were allocated.

How come? Isn't this using 4000 bytes of memory?

Comment: Maybe `int`s are only 2 bytes ? Try printing `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: You're right! However, the 'problem' still persists when I up it to 2000 `ints`...

Comment: Are you using the mbed development board that comes with the expansion kit ? That gives you extra RAM.

Comment: Nope. I have got one, I'm just not using it atm.

Comment: OK - the only other thing I can think of then is that you may be seeing modulo addressing (i.e. wraparound of addresses every 2k bytes) - see if you can write different values to your array at indices 0, 1024, 2048, 3072, 4096 - I suspect that as you'll find that you get the same value from any of these locations when you read them back.

Comment: Like this? http://pastebin.com/qqchghDS

This prints "1 2 3 4" on the lcd.

Comment: I tried this code: http://pastebin.com/MtJDBNKk. And the thing really freaked out, it started moving backwards and making weird noises o_o.

Comment: Sorry - I'm running out of ideas - check the data sheet and see if there is a memory map that would help to make sense of what you're seeing.

Comment: Well, when I assign every element in the array to a value, it behaves as expected and produces unexpected results because it ran out of memory, which is what I expected to happen. I guess the definition of `nums` isn't actually creating `1000 * 2` bytes in memory?

I've basically got what I'm after now anyway, the array elements only take up memory when they are assigned a value.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense - I'm guessing that when you overflow SRAM you're finding something else that's writeable, such as scratchpad memory, or registers, or maybe EEPROM/flash memory. Anyway, I guess the bottom line is that you just need to stay within the available 2 kb otherwise weird and unpredictable things will happen ! ;-)

Comment: Ah ok, that would make sense. Thanks!